# Extract huge tar.gz archives from S3 without copying archives to a local system

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, tar

I'm looking for a way to extract huge dataset (18 TB+ found here https://github.com/cvdfoundation/open-images-dataset#download-images-with-bounding-boxes-annotations) with this in mind I need the process to be fast (i.e. I don't want to spend twice the time for first copying and then extracting files) Also I don't want archives to take extra space not even one 20 gb+ archive.

Any thoughts on how one can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange to pipe the data straight into `tar`, it can uncompress and extract it without needing a temporary file.

Here is a example. First create a tar file to play with

```
$ echo abc >one
$ echo def >two
$ tar cvf test.tar
$ tar cvf test.tar one two
one
two
$ gzip test.tar
```

Remove the test files

```
$ rm one two
$ ls one two
ls: cannot access one: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access two: No such file or directory
```

Now extract the contents by piping the compressed tar file into the `tar` command.

```
$ cat test.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
one
two
$ ls one two
one  two
```

The only part missing now is how to download the data and pipe it into tar. Assuming you can access the URL with `wget`, you can get it to send the data to stdout. So you end up with this

```
wget -qO- https://youtdata | tar xzvf -
```